# Почему в одних случаях django устанавливает заголовок Content-Range, а в других нет?

Tags: django

есть страничка, на которую подгружается 3 трека через ajax
Под капотом находится django с примерно таким выхлопом:

```
response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False), content_type="application/json")
response["Accept-Range"] = "bytes"
return response
```

Но дает такая конструкция ровно те же результаты, что давала и предыдущая:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False), content_type="application/json")
```

А именно: только к одному треку (и то через раз) заголовок Content-Range присоединяется, к двум другим ни в какую
Подскажите пожалуйста, отчего зависит автоматизация этого процесса в django и укажите мне, что я делаю не так

Comment: Django не может устанавливать заголовок Content-Range, ничего подобного в принципе нет в его коде

Comment: @Andrei Как ты понимаешь значение этого заголовка? Почему ты так хочешь его вставить туда?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы клиент мог перематывать запись, для этого нужен заголовок Content-Range
По совершенно непонятным мне причинам один трек из трех с django приходит с этим заголовком, остальные без него

Comment: Поэтому я и считаю, что как-то этот заголовок можно установить

Comment: Сейчас более пристально изучил, что откуда идет и обратил внимание, что совершенно не то делал
Я устанавливал заголовки в ответе на получение ссылок на аудио, а не на сами ссылки
Грубо говоря, у меня есть ajax-функция, возвращающая список аудио для дальнейшего их отображения на странице, но сами-то аудио с соответствующими заголовками берутся непосредственно из /static/media/...
Поэтому мне действительно стоит сделать отдельную функцию для обработки этого адреса, как показано здесь:

Comment: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/28436/

Comment: Я ведь правильно поступаю?

Comment: Ааа, нашел решение

Comment: В общем после всего мною вышесказанного нужно обязательно дать 206 сигнал от сервера, то есть response.status_code = 206

Comment: Статические файлы вроде аудио нужно раздавать через специализированный веб-сервер вроде nginx, а Django тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: А подскажите, что считается статическими файлами, то есть что нужно поручать nginx?

Comment: Вот например да, аудио, это статический файл, но получается и изображения, и видео, и другие форматы загружаемых пользователем файлов тоже являются статическими?

Comment: Но считаются ли файлы фронтенда статическими, то есть .html, .css, .js, которые хранятся в папке static и template?